# JBoss 7.1.1 not logging

Tags: logging, jboss7.x

We have two applications that use SLF4J for logging.

In one application everything works fine, the other does not log.
This means, no log statements show up in server.log except for `System.out.println`.

- no dependency on slf4j module declared
- No error is displayed (missing dependencies on slf4j).
- Both applications use the same category.
- The war file does not contain any logging libraries

Because I cannot further narrow down the question, I am looking for reasons why log statements might not show up in server.log.

Comment: Provide more details regarding your problem. Are you using a logback.xml file for logging configuration.?

Comment: What version of JBoss AS? Also what do you mean by "no dependency on slf4j module declared"?